# How to config no reference table in api

Tags: c#, .net

i had project and i want to throw api for mobile appilcation.

I design on: `Domain Driven Design pattern.`

I have table:

`Table A: ID, Name, Location`

`Table B: ID, IDTableA, PropertiesName...`

When i select all data from table B, api returns sample:

```
data{
ID: 1
PropertiesName:....
TableA:{
         data:[]....
       }
}
```

I don't know how to get data from table B not have data from table A.

I also config in WebAPIConfig in Api but it not success:

```
ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Help me please!
My english is so bad.
Sorry for convenience

Comment: The API controls how the data is sent down. Do you have access to it? IT sounds like table b depends on table a so the data is married.

Comment: Yes A is related to B, like with a foreign key, that is why you have a column IDTableA in Table B.

Comment: Yes, A is related to B, but when get data from that, i don't want to get data from related table.

Comment: You can use required fields in query like GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/accounts?$select=name,revenue, refer here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx

Comment: @Botonomous i had config reference, but not success.